Use of Clausius theorem to prove entropy inequality in Fermi's Thermodynamics
At the beginning of Section 13 (at the bottom half of page 54 through the top half of page 55) of Enrico Fermi's classic Thermodynamics, he sets out to prove the relation (using his notation)
$$S(B) - S(A) \ge \int_A^B \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} $$
for an irreversible thermodynamic process between an initial state $A$ and final state $B$. To prove this inequality, Fermi argues that one can form a cycle by joining to the irreversible transformation a reversible transformation from $A$ to $B$ run in reverse, i.e., from $B$ to $A$. He then applies the Clausius inequality (introduced and proved on pages 46-47)
$$ \oint \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} \le 0 ,$$
deducing the desired result by decomposing the left-hand side of the above inequality into two integrals, (namely $(\int_A^B dQ/T)_I$ and $(\int_B^A dQ/T)_R)$), the latter of which he evaluates using results obtained in the preceding pages.
My issue is as follows:
The Wikipedia article for the Clausius theorem, in contrast to Fermi's treatment, takes great expository and notational care in specifying that the Clausius inequality concerns the entropy change of thermal reservoirs surrounding the system of interest, heat flow into which system is taken to be positive, so that
$$\oint \frac{\delta Q}{T_{\mathrm{Surr}}} \le 0 \Longleftrightarrow \Delta S_{\mathrm{Res}}= \oint \mathrm{d} S_{\mathrm{Res}} = \oint \frac{-\delta Q}{T_{\mathrm{Surr}}} \ge 0, $$
which is consistent with my prior understanding that a thermodynamic cycle cannot decrease the entropy of its surroundings (per cycle).
With all this in mind, to which 'part' of the universe (i.e., the system or the surroundings) is Fermi referring when he writes (in his notation)
$$ 0 \ge \oint \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} = \left ( \int_A^B \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} \right )_{\! I} + \left ( \int_B^A \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} \right )_{\! R} =\, \left ( \int_A^B \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} \right )_{\! I} - \left ( \int_A^B \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} \right )_{\! R}, $$
given that he then obtains the desired result by equating $\left ( \int_A^B \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T} \right )_{R}$ to the entropy change $S(B) - S(A)$ of the system in passing from state $A$ to state $B$? It looks to me as if Fermi has pulled a fast one by equating the integral in the Clausius theorem, which pertains to the surroundings, to two integrals which, based on the preceding pages, appear to concern the entropy of the system.
To put it another way, if I were to try to translate Fermi's argument into Wikipedia's notation, would it look like this
$$ 0 \ge \oint \frac{\delta Q}{T_{\mathrm{Surr}}} = \int_{\mathrm{Irr},\, A\to B} \frac{\delta Q}{T_{\mathrm{Surr}}} +  \int_{\mathrm{Rev},\,B \to A}\frac{\delta Q}{T_{\mathrm{Surr}}}, $$
or something else? If the above is correct, then how can Fermi use such integrals (which treat the temperature of the surroundings) to make statements about the entropy of the system without further justification?

The Clausius inequality applies to the net entropy transfer to the system (heat engine)

@BobD If that's the case, then how am I to interpret the first paragraph of the linked Wikipedia article? Is it simply wrong when it gives the inequality in terms of the negative entropy change of the reservoir(s) $-\oint \mathrm{d}S_{\mathrm{Res}} = -\Delta S_{\mathrm{Res}}$, i.e. the entropy change of the surroundings?

See my response to your comment on my answer


With all this in mind, to which 'part' of the universe (i.e., the
system or the surroundings) is Fermi referring when he writes (in his
notation)
$$ 0 \ge \oint \frac{\mathrm{d}Q}{T}  =…$$

The Clausius inequality refers to the heat engine (system).
It says for a reversible cycle the entropy entering the heat engine from the surrounding equals the entropy leaving the heat engine to the surroundings. On the other hand, for a cycle where part(s) of the cycle is irreversible, the entropy leaving the heat engine is greater than the entropy entering the heat engine, the difference being the entropy generated by the heat engine over the irreversible part(s) of the cycle.
In effect, it says in order for the system to return to its original state it must rid itself of any entropy generated by the heat engine by transferring entropy to the surroundings. The only way to transfer entropy is by means of heat.
Fermi notation:
Part of the confusion stems from Fermi's notation, specifically the. lack of notation.
On page 54 he writes:
$$S(B)-S(A)=\int_A^B\frac{dQ}{T}\tag{1}$$
"Provided the integral is taken over a reversible transformation from A to B"
Then he writes "If, however, the integral is taken from A to B over an irreversible transformation, the preceding equation no longer holds. We shall show in that case that we have, instead, the inequality
$$S(B)-S(A)\ge\int_A^B\frac{dQ}{T}\tag{2}$$
Although he states the first equation applies to a reversible transformation, having the same expression on the right side of both equations can, in my view, lead to confusion. Generally, the first equation, which is the definition of entropy change for any process,is written as
$$S(B)-S(A)=\int_A^B\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}\tag{3}$$
to clearly indicate the right side of equation (1) applies to a reversible transfer of heat, whereas the right side of equation (2) is not a reversible transfer of heat. $T$ in equation (2) is sometimes written as $T_{B}$ to emphasize the temperature is that of the boundary between the system and the surroundings, not the temperature of the system.
Then, given that equation (3) applies for any process (reversible or irreversible), we can calculate the entropy generated, symbol $\sigma$, in the irreversible cycle as
$$S(B)-S(A)=\int_A^B \frac{dQ}{T_{B}}+\sigma\tag{4}$$
Or equivalently
$$\int_A^B\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T}=\int_A^B \frac{dQ}{T_{B}}+\sigma\tag{5}$$
Where $T_B$ is understood to be the temperature at the boundary between the system and the thermal reservoir in the surroundings, and not the system temperature. The entropy generated, $\sigma$ is the difference between the entropy sent to the surroundings a the entropy sent to the system in the Clausius inequality.
For an additional reference you might find helpful, see http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/thermo/clausius.html#c1
Hope this helps.

Your first couple sentences, "The Clausius inequality refers to the heat engine (system). It says for a reversible cycle the entropy entering the heat engine from the surrounding equals the entropy leaving the heat engine to the surroundings." seem to directly contradict the first couple paragraphs of the linked Wikipedia article. Is the article wrong, or am I misinterpreting its verbiage and notation?

The second paragraph of the Wiki article states, "The Clausius theorem or inequality obviously implies $ \oint dS_{\text{Res}}\ge 0$ per thermodynamic cycle, meaning that the entropy of the reservoirs increases or does not change, and never decreases, per cycle." By Wikipedia's notation, the only quantity pertaining to the system occurring in the Clausius inequality is the heat $\delta Q$ added to the cycle (system), and the interpretation given by the article concerns the entropy change of the surroundings, not the system.

@user104761 I see no contradiction. To say more entropy enters the reservoirs than leaves the reservoirs (per Wikipedia) is the same thing as saying more entropy leaves system than enters the system(per my answer and the Hyperphysics article). And how can you not agree that, for a reversible cycle, the entropy entering the heat engine equals the entropy leaving the heat engine? Did you read the Hyperphysics article?

I do agree with your latter statement. My issue is to with the case of the irreversible system, viz. Fermi's equating the integral $ \oint \mathrm{d} Q/T = \oint \delta Q / T_{\mathrm{Surr}} $ which (according to the Wikipedia article, anyway) concerns the entropy change of the surroundings to two integrals which appear to be taken over paths representing state changes of the system without any explicit justification. I don't doubt that there exists some thermodynamic principle by which one might equate those quantities, but in no answer offered thus far has that step been justified.

To be clear, I'm not disagreeing with anyone's interpretations of the physics, most of which have been correct and helpful in aiding my understanding of the result. What I'm trying to understand here is Fermi's method of proof, which appears to take an unjustified or implicit step. In particular, there must be some intermediate argument, identity, or relation which justifies Fermi's equating the Clausius theorem integral $-\oint \mathrm{d}S_{\mathrm{Res}} = -\Delta S_{\mathrm{Res}}$ with the system integrals which was assumed obvious by Fermi, but which I'm still not seeing.

@user104761 I don't know why the Wikipedia article talks about the Clausius theorem in terms of the reservoirs (which I personally find confusing) while virtually all other sources clearly refer to the system. Instead of trying to compare Fermi to Wikipedia, what issue due you have with the Fermi proof on its own merits.

That's a fair question, but I'm afraid that my issue with Fermi's proof is independent of the Wikipedia article and its notation. Indeed, it was my unsuccessful attempts to reconcile Fermi's own treatment of the Clausius theorem on pages 46-48 with his proof which led me to the Wikipedia article in the first place. My initial confusion with Fermi's proof is exactly as stated in the original question: How can Fermi equate an integral which (in Fermi's development as well as Wiki's) is explicitly introduced as pertaining only to the reservoirs to two integrals taken over system quantities?

@user104761 I am willing to continue with this in an attempt to resolve your issues but I think we should continue in Chat rather than in comments if you wish

I wasn't aware that this website maintained any direct messaging functionality, but I'm happy to continue this dialogue wherever you think is best. Thank you for all your help so far.

To get a better sense as to why I remain confused by Fermi's identification of the Clausius integral with the other two integrals in his proof, cf. footnote 1 on page 48. In actuality, based on the content of that note, the inconsistencies really begin on the following page, when Fermi sets out to define the entropy of a system using the same kind of integral he used in stating and proving the Clausius theorem $\int \rm{d} Q/T$, seemingly contradicting note 1.

@user104761 I am willing to discuss the Fermi material with you, but the discussion may be lengthy so we need to do it in Chat. If you agree please set up a Chat room for us

Thanks Bob, will do.

I'm sorry, it looks like I have insufficient reputation privileges to set up a Chat room. Apologies for the confusion.

@user104761. I’ll set it up

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

All mysteries go away if you realize that when you say $dQ$ (or $\delta Q$) heat is supplied from the reservoir whose temperature is $T_e$ then along with said heat the reservoir supplies $dS_e=\frac{\delta Q}{T_e}$ entropy. In fact, one cannot supply heat without supplying entropy, the two always go together; one might say that supplying entropy at some temperature is what heat is. Then Clausius's inequality between two equilibrium states $A \to B$ along the reversible path $\mathcal C$ is the statement that $$\int_A^B dS_e(\mathcal C) \le S(B)-S(A)=\Delta S \tag{1},$$ or in words, the supplied entropy from the environment never exceeds the entropy change of the system itself. Here $dS_e(\mathcal C)$ denotes the absorbed (positive) or rejected (negative) differential entropy by the system supplied by its environment at various stages of the reversible path $\mathcal C$. The temperature $T_e$ at which the heat (entropy) is exchanged with environment may be variable, the only assumption is that the exchange be reversible.
The discrepancy between the left and right sides is the internally generated entropy in the system by the irreversible process connecting the two equilibrium states $A$ and $B$.
If, despite the irreversibility, you can define states and with it entropy along the irreversible process, and this is a non-trivial assumption underlying all of arguments, Fermi's or Wikipedia's, etc., then you can say that $$dS_e \le dS\tag{2}$$ always where $dS$ denotes the differential increment of the system's entropy at any stage of the process be it reversible or irreversible, and then it follows trivially its integral form :
$$\int_A^B dS_e(\mathcal C) \le \int_A^B dS(\mathcal P)\tag{3}$$
where now $\mathcal P$ denotes an arbitrary reversible or irreversible path connecting two equilibrium states $A$ and $B$. In Eq.3 the left side is the total entropy supplied by the environment to the system and the right side is the total amount of entropy change within the system while it exchanges the amount of entropy represented by the left side.

This is a helpful clarification of the meaning of Fermi's result $\Delta S \ge \int_A^B dQ/T$ but I still don't understand how one can decompose the Clausius integral $\oint \delta Q / T_{\mathrm{Surr}} $ in this way without some other intermediate computation or argument given that the quantity represented by this integral pertains to the entropy of the surroundings and not to the system (cf. the first paragraph of the linked Wiki article). What permits us to split a quantity giving the (negative) entropy change of the surroundings into two integrals taken strictly over system quantities?

A heat (entropy) reservoir can  participate in only one kind of interaction: it supplies/absorbs heat (entropy) at a fixed given unchanging temperature irrespective of its rate and this interaction of the reservoir is always reversible within the reservoir. In other words, if the reservoir supplies/absorbs $\Delta S_e$ entropy (or $T_e\Delta S_e$ heat) then it reduces/increases its own entropy exactly by the same amount. This is the definition of a reservoir, ...

....just like we define an ideal voltage source by assuming that its voltage does not change irrespective of the amount of charge (or current) it supplies/absorbs. When we consider the interaction of a thermodynamic system with a reservoir or with a sequence of reservoirs at various temperatures we know the amount of entropy these reservoirs supply/absorb. This is what a calorimeter does. Beyond the  calorimetric measurement at the boundary we have Clausius's inequality: the total entropy change in the reservoir + in the system $\ge 0$ with equality iff the process is reversible.

And this inequality holds irrespective of what other non-heat work interaction the system may participate in.

"if the reservoir supplies/absorbs ΔSe entropy (or TeΔSe heat) then it reduces/increases its own entropy exactly by the same amount." If that's the case, then can we equate the (negative) reservoir entropy change given by integral $\oint \delta Q / T_{\mathrm{Surr}} = -\Delta S_{\mathrm{Res}}$ occurring in the Clausius theorem to the entropy change of the system $\Delta S_{\mathrm{Sys}}$ in the irreversible case of interest to Fermi's proof?

And if not, then is there some other identity or relation which explicitly links these two quantities $\Delta S_{\mathrm{Sys}}$ and $-\Delta S_{\mathrm{Res}}$ in the irreversible case which is neither dependent on nor derived from the inequality to be proved?

Inside the reservoir everything is reversible operationally meaning that whatever crosses its boundary going into it  at (-0) is exactly by how much the inside at +0 is, no change in the amount, and vice versa. This is not the same with the "system" that can have internally irreversible processes. Whatever goes in through its boundary from the outside - this being now the reservoir- will be inside the system and to which a certain positive amount of entropy is internally generated by the system.

In other words, total gravitational mass, total electric charge, total volume, etc., are conserved quantities but entropy is a "para-conserved" quantity that can stay the same in a reversible process or increase in an irreversible process. The total entropy (system + surrounding) does not decrease, this is the essence of the 2nd law and is expressed by the inequality of Clausius. How much entropy increases in a process is constitutive relationship of the system that cannot be formulated in general but depends on the specific material and its interactions.

Start by the definition of entropy. By definition:
$$
S(B)-S(A) = \int_{Rev,\,A\to B}\frac{\delta Q}{T_e}
$$
for any reversible path from $A\to B$. The definition is well posed since Clausius' inequality becomes an equality and the integral is path independent. You can further simplify it by noticing that reversibility of the process implies that the system's temperature and the surrounding's temperature are equal (by the contraposition of Clausius' formulation of the second principle):
$$
T_e = T
$$
so:
$$
S(B)-S(A) = \int_{Rev,\,A\to B}\frac{\delta Q}T
$$
If I recall correctly, Fermi mentions this fact in a previous section. Using the split of the cycle:
$$
S(B)-S(A) \geq \int_{A\to B}\frac{\delta Q}{T_e}
$$
where in the RHS, the temperature in the integrand is the surrounding temperature and you have equality iff the path is reversible.

But what do the latter two integrals have to do with the Clausius theorem, which, judging from the introduction to the Wikipedia article I linked, has to do with the entropy change of the thermal reservoirs, i.e., the surroundings? In particular, how can we decompose the Clausius integral $- \oint \mathrm{d}S_{\mathrm{Res}}$ into two integrals taken over quantities of the system, then use those results to make statements about the system's entropy without invoking any additional argument or identity linking $\Delta S_{\mathrm{Res}} $ with $\Delta S_{\mathrm{Sys}}$?

In Clausius' inequality, it is the entropy of the system which is relevant. A motivation for entropy is precisely to get rid of the environment's influence and recover a state function depending only on the system. The wikipedia's notation $S_{res}$ is misleading, because it is ill defined mathematically. $S_{res}$ is not a state function, since the closed path integral is not always zero. My final equation corresponds to wikipedia's "generalized inequality of Clausius."

Notation-wise,  the quantity $dS-\delta Q/T_e$ is called the created entropy and Clausius theorem states that it is always positive. Once again, it is not a state function, and even as a differential, it depends on the path chosen.

If we trust that temperature is a positive quantity and heat "goes from hot bodies to cold bodies", everything should follow quite naturally. In this answer, I'm focusing on the elementary Clausius inequality; you can derive the conclusion you need with integration along a transformation.
Let's focus on the elementary form of Clausius inequality,
$$dS \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ ,$$
being $S$ the entropy of the system, $T$ it's temperature (assumed to be homogeneous) and $\delta Q$ the heat flux from the environment to the system.
If the heat flux "goes from hot to cold bodies", $\delta Q \ge 0$ if $T^{env} - T \ge 0$, and  $\delta Q \le 0$ if $T^{env} - T \le 0$. This can be written as
$$\delta Q (T^{env} - T) \ge 0 \quad 
\rightarrow \quad \delta Q \, T^{env} \ge \delta Q \, T \quad
\rightarrow \quad \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T^{env}} \ ,$$
if we believe that $T \ge 0$. Thus, Clausis inequality (that is referred to the system) can be used to write
$$dS \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T} \ge \frac{\delta Q}{T^{env}} = - dS^{env} \ $$
and thus
$$d S^{tot} = d S + d S^{env} \ge 0 \ .$$

Is this you, @chet? <3

The easiest way to understand the Clausius inequality is to recognize that entropy is a state function and that, for a closed system (no mass in or out during a process between two thermodynamic equilibrium states), the entropy of the system can change by only two mechanisms (see Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics):

Entropy flow across the boundary of the system between the system and surroundings by heat flow dQ at the boundary temperature $T_B$ (boundary between the system and surroundings):  $$\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}$$This mechanism is present in both reversible and irreversible processes, and, for an irreversible process, the boundary temperature  differs from the system temperature only infinitesimally ($T_B=T)$.

Entropy generated $\sigma$ within the system as a result of irreversibly within the system, where $sigma$ is always positive. For a reversible process, $\sigma=0$.


So, for a closed system in general, the total change in entropy is equal to $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}+\sigma$$
For a reversible path, this reduces to $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T_{rev}}}$$Since entropy is a state function, all reversible paths between the same two end states must give the same value for the integral.
So, combining the previous two equations, we have $$\Delta S=\int{\frac{dQ}{T_B}}+\sigma=\ \int{\frac{dQ_{rev}}{T_{rev}}}$$

I can't believe this was down voted! The reason should be given.

@BobD shocking!  I think that someone just doesn’t like me personally.

Kind of like “hit and run”
